# choose the correct option regarding complete metric space

Tags: general-topology

let $X= \mathbb{N}$,the  set of postive integer  consider  the metrics $d_1,d_2 $  on $X$  given by
$d_1(m,n) =|m-n|$ , $m , n  \in X $

$d_2(m,n) =|\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n}|$ , $m ,n  \in X $

let $X_1,X_2$  denotes   the metric space  $(X,d_1),(X,d_2)$ respectively .Then
choose the coorect option

$1.$  $X_1$   is  complete

$2.$ $X_2$  is complete

$3.$ $X_1$ is totally bounded

$4.$ $X_2$  is totally  bounded

My attempt : I got  option  $1)$  and option $3)$ beacuse the sequence $x_n = n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a Cauchy sequence for $d$. And $(x_n)$ don't converge to a limit.

is  its true

Any hints/solution will be  appreciated
thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is OK, as Cauchy sequences are eventually constant.
2. is false, indeed, as $x_n= n$ is a non-convergent Cauchy sequence.
3. is false, as we cannot cover $X$ by finitely many balls of radius $1$.
4. is true, as we can compactify it by adding a single point, e.g.

Answer (score 1):

For point $4.$, to explicitly see that $X_2$ is totally bounded, fix $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N > 3/\epsilon.$ Then for any $M > N$, we see $$d_2(N,M) = \left \lvert \frac 1 N - \frac 1 M \right \rvert \le \frac 1 N + \frac 1 M \le 2\epsilon/3 < \epsilon.$$ Thus the set $\{ m \in \mathbb N \, : \, m \ge N\}$ is contained in $B_\epsilon(N)$. Thus the collection $\{B_\epsilon(n)\}^N_{n=1}$ forms a finite cover of $\mathbb N$ by balls of radius $\epsilon$.

The rest of the points can be elucidated with simple examples, as in the answer by @HennoBrandsma.